# Powershell Classes constructor called twice - using module and Import-Module

Tags: powershell

Update:

```
Scary scary, restarting the computer helped. 
I will keep it, if someone encounter this.
```

Setup:

```
Powershell version: 6.2.1
MacOs: Catalina
```

I am using Classe, so I have to use "using module" to be able to reference classes.

I am also using "Import-Module" to load modules.

But now i get some strange behaviour - class constructer called twice and same file opened twice in VSCode.

Loading:

```
Import-Module module_one.psm1
Import-Module module_two.psm1
```

In module_one.psm1:

```
Class MyClass {
  MyClass(){} # << This is called twice
}
```

In module_two.psm1:

```
using module module_one.psm1
[MyClass]::new()
```

Is there no way to use Classes with "Import-Module"?

Comment: What is the version of PS you are trying on? I tried on 5.1 and it calls only once

Comment: Thanks for verifying - I am on 6. 2. 3

Comment: same result with 6.2.3 as well, Only thing I changed is `[MyClass]::new()` but I am on windows 10

Comment: Ok, interesting...